# Posting array to c# web service object issue

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, web-services

I have been having a issue when I post form data to my webservice. When I debug the web service the parameter messagepost has a count of 1 but the object data is empty, but when I look at the object in the request I can see that the object is populated. I've been searching and racking my brain for an hour and can't see me to get it to work. So maybe someone here can help me out.

Javascript

```
function getEmptyLeg() {

        var chkTail = $("#elTail").is(':checked');
        var chkType = $("#elType").is(':checked');
        var chkNBAA = $("#chkNBAA").is(':checked');
        var chkCategory = $("#elCategory").is(':checked');

        var itineraryList = new Array();

        var itinerary = new Object();
        itinerary.Time = "";
        itinerary.Arrival = $("#elTo").val();
        itinerary.Departure = $("#elFrom").val();
        itinerary.ArrivalDate = getDate("#elEndDate");
        itinerary.DepartureDate = getDate("#elStartDate");
        itineraryList.push(itinerary);

        var messagepost = new Object();
        messagepost.Types = "";
        messagepost.Categories = "";
        messagepost.ShowTail = chkTail;
        messagepost.ShowType = chkType;
        messagepost.SendToNBAA = chkNBAA;
        messagepost.DirectoryAircraft = false;
        messagepost.ShowCategory = chkCategory;
        messagepost.Price = $("#elPrice").val();
        messagepost.NBAAEmail = $("#txtEmail").val();
        messagepost.MessageItinerary = itineraryList;
        messagepost.AircraftID = $("select#elAircraft").val();                       

        return messagepost;
    }

function saveMessage() {

        var options = "";
        var type = $("#hdfType").val();
        var userid = $('#<%= hdfUserID.ClientID %>').val();
        var message = $("#<%= txtMessage.ClientID %>").val();
        var timezone = $('#<%= hdfTimezone.ClientID %>').val();

        $('#<%= sltUsers.ClientID %> option:selected').each(function (i) {
            options += $(this).val() + ",";
        });

        var messagepost = new Array();
        messagepost.push(getEmptyLeg());


        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/Resources/MessageWebService.asmx/SaveMessage",
            data: "{ 'message':'" + message + "',"
                    + "'options':'" + options + "',"
                    + "'url':'" + $(location).attr('href') + "',"
                    + "'userid':'" + userid + "',"
                    + "'messageid':'" + 0 + "',"
                    + "messagepost:" + JSON.stringify(messagepost) + ","
                    + "'postType':'" + type + "' }",
            success: function (data) {                            

                    $('#messages').prepend($(data.d).fadeIn('slow'));

                    growlMessage('Message was successfully');
                },
            error: function (data) {
                showError(data.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

web service

```
[WebMethod]
public string SaveMessage(string message, string options, string url, string userid, string messageid, List<MessagePost> messagepost, string postType) {
}
```

Request from chrome

```
{ 'message':'empty leg','options':'Public,','url':'http://localhost/portal/quote.aspx?qid=254','userid':'d2703dd0-c743-4995-ac93-5cfab7fa5205','messageid':'0',messagepost:[{"Types":"","Categories":"","ShowTail":true,"ShowType":true,"SendToNBAA":true,"DirectoryAircraft":false,"ShowCategory":true,"Price":"2500","NBAAEmail":"chad.neiro@avianis.com","MessageItinerary":[{"Time":"","Arrival":"KSAN","Departure":"ENNA","ArrivalDate":"12/21/2012","DepartureDate":"12/21/2012"}]}],'postType':'4' }
```

message post class

```
public class MessagePost
{        
    Boolean ShowTail { get; set; }
    Boolean ShowType { get; set; }
    Boolean SendToNBAA { get; set; }
    Boolean ShowCategory { get; set; }
    Boolean DirectoryAircraft { get; set; }

    string Types { get; set; }
    string Price { get; set; }
    string NBAAEmail { get; set; }        
    string AircraftID { get; set; }
    string Categories { get; set; }

    List<MessageItinerary> ItineraryList { get; set; }
}

public class MessageItinerary
{
    string Time { get; set; }
    string Arrival { get; set; }
    string Departure { get; set; }
    string ArrivalDate { get; set; }
    string DepartureDate { get; set; }
    string Preference { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It may help if you posted the server-side code for the MessagePost class (and any custom classes inside it).

Comment: Would this work with JSON? I thought .aspx WebMethod only accepts SOAP. Can you try either posting as application/x-www-form-urlencoded and use a standard Page_Load() to process this or switch to MVC?

Comment: @EugeneOsovetsky I posted the server-side code above. and yes I have the web service working when posting a string, I only starting running into this problem when trying to post an array to my web method.

Comment: finally figured it out. a long week of work really got me on this one. the object properties were not public. once I made the properties public it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Like saarps suggests in the comments, I also believe this has to do with JSON and deserialization of the data.

I gave up paramaters in my WebMethods early, and retrieve the data from the Request instead.
Example, the following code:

```
[WebMethod]
public string SaveMessage(string message) {
    //Do something
}
```

would instead be written like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public string SaveMessage() {
    string message = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["message"];
    //Do something
}
```